# Functional tests and fileuploads?

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-2.3

I have a Symfony2 entity called `MyUploadedFiles` and a form type `MyUploadedFilesType` with the name `myuploadedfiles`. This form type builds a form with a single field `file`. This field should not be blank and the rest of the data in the entity is generated, once a user uploads a file. Now, I want to run a functional test for my controller that handles the upload. But I I always get the error `file should not be blank`.

This is the code in my `myUploadTest` method:

```
   $filepath = __DIR__.'/test_file.xml';
   $xmlfile = new UploadedFile(
        $filepath,
        'foo.xml',
        'text/xml',
        \filesize($filepath)
    );
    $client->request(
        'POST',
        '/path/to/xml_upload',
        array(),
        array('myuploadedfiles[file]' => $xmlfile)
    );  

    $response = $client->getResponse();

    $this->assertEquals(Codes::HTTP_CREATED, $response->getStatusCode());
```

The controller looks like:

```
   $form->bind($request);
   if ($form->isValid()) { ... }
```

If I render the form with a twig template and try to upload something everything works fine. So probably the error is somewhere in the test code.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I use this code:

```
# Select the file from the filesystem
# Path of the file to send
$filepath = __DIR__.'/test_file.xml';
$xmlfile = new UploadedFile(
    $filepath,
    'foo.xml',
    'text/xml',
    \filesize($filepath)
);

# Select the form (adapt it for your needs)
$form = $crawler->filter('input[type=submit]...')->form();

# Put the file in the upload field
$form['myuploadedfiles[file]']->upload($xmlfile);

# Send it
$crawler = $this->client->submit($form);

# Check that the file has been successfully sent 
#  (in my case the filename is displayed in a <a> link so I check
#  that it appears on the page)
$this->assertEquals(
    1,
    $crawler->filter('a:contains("foo.xml")')->count()
);
```